# Create ListBoxItem property

Tags: wpf, properties, triggers, listbox, datatemplate

I have two ListBox's and a Button.  The Button sends List1.SelectedItems over to List2.  I would like to add a visual cue for the items in List1 that have been added to List2, similar to how there is a visual cue when items are selected.  Is it possible to add a property to them so that this can be accomplished?

```
 _______             _______
|       |     _     |       |
| List1 |    |>|    | List2 |
|_______|           |_______|
```

Here is an example of using the IsSelected property to modify the background.

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers> 
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True"> 
        <Setter TargetName="listItem" Property="Background" Value="Blue" /> 
    </Trigger> 
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

I would like to add an additional property, called "IsAdded", which would also affect the background if set to True.  Is something like that possible, or is there an alternative approach to this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just remove it from List1?

Comment: The issue with that is you have to keep a clean copy of List1, so when the items move back to List1, you know where to insert them.  Also this particular implementation its just ideal to keep them in the list but with some sort of UI cue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you use `ViewModel` class, or similar to this to represent you items. What you need - is to add the property IsAdded to the item class, and, when you handle `Button.Click` event (or more better - your `ViewModel` has `ICommand` property which inserts selected items in List1 to List2), you can sad to the selected items which was added to the List2 that they are was added.

```
private bool isAdded;
public bool IsAdded
{
    get { return isAdded; }
    set
    {
        if (isAdded == value)
            return;
        isAdded = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsAdded");
    }
}
```

where `OnPropertyChanged` method will raise an `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface ([see msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)).

When you handle `Button.Click`, you know which elements to be added, so put this line of code there:

```
...
foreach(var item in List1.SelectedItems)
{
    item.IsAdded = true;
}
...
```

And than, add to your `DataTemplate.Triggers` collection the following trigger:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsAdded, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="listItem" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer I was looking for